# Flutter: How Do I Make This Shape Rotate Smoothly Using a GestureDetector?

Tags: flutter, gesturedetector

**Introduction:**

I have begun studying rotations in Flutter using the following code which is supposed to rotate a square by using a GestureDetector:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  double angle = 0.0;
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  void _panHandler(DragUpdateDetails d) {
    setState(() {
      widget.angle = atan(d.delta.dy / d.delta.dx);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: GestureDetector(
        onPanUpdate: _panHandler,
        child: Center(
          child: Transform.rotate(
            angle: this.widget.angle,
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.red,
              child: SizedBox(
                child: null,
                height: 100,
                width: 100,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Problem:** 
Indeed, the square does rotate; however, it is anything but smooth. It flickers badly while spinning. I am puzzled by this and do not know how to make it turn smoothly.

**Question:**

1) Does this problem arise from some sort of decimal precision issue or my maths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  double angle = 0.0;

  void _onPanUpdateHandler(DragUpdateDetails details) {
    final touchPositionFromCenter = details.localPosition;
    setState(
      () {
        angle = touchPositionFromCenter.direction;
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
          child: GestureDetector(
        onPanUpdate: _onPanUpdateHandler,
        child: Transform.rotate(
          angle: angle,
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.red,
            child: SizedBox(
              child: null,
              height: 100,
              width: 100,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This works fantastically snj. I am trying to figure out from the documentation how it works. So, the DragUpdateDetails.localPosition gives back an angle. This is fantastic to know! I suppose it was engineered this way to be so smooth. Thank you for the eloquent answer!